# DIV with Overflow won't scroll on Android devices

Tags: android, html, css, overflow

Auto and scroll seem to work fine for overflow on my DIVs on an iPhone, but they seem to be non-functional on any Android devices, has anyone come across anything like this before?

[EDITED 8-22-2012 14:02]

This seems to be a bug with Android browsers, does anyone know of any fixes or workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Android.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911

Comment: I'm assuming from that post that Google either hasn't or has no intention of fixing this issue, or providing a workaround?